# Createjs : Container.getBounds() and Container.getTransformedBounds() returns null

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I have a container and I have added a couple of bitmaps to it and scaled the whole container. Now when I call getTransformedBounds() on it, it returns null.

```
   let innerContainer = new createjs.Container();
   innerContainer.addChild(bitmap1);
   innerContainer.addChild(bitmap2);
   innerContainer.scaleX=scale;
   innerContainer.scaleY=scale;
   let phBounds = innerContainer.getTransformedBounds();
```

Here phBounds is null. It was working all these days. Suddenly today it is returning null. Strange.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you wait for the `Bitmap` image to load? If not, the bounds will be null because there is no content to measure. I wrote a quick test, and everything looks like its working fine:

https://codepen.io/gskinner/pen/bWEoaQ